# FQL: Unable to process on Facebook side

Tags: facebook-fql

I am looking for the reason for occasional FQL failure. Our script will run smoothly most of the time but occasionally it will fail for anywhere from several minutes to several hours producing the following error message:

Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected 'ORDER' at position 70

I have attempted on numerous occasions to remove the ORDER BY clause from my queries in hopes that the FQL could then process in Facebook. This has always resulted in yet another failure; typically, giving an error that states "Unexpected End of Query".

Any insight will be much appreciated!

Example query:

SELECT aid, object_id, created, description FROM album WHERE owner = $pageID ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your query miss substitution for `$pageID` because it's empty. That exception will occur in that case.

- Ensure that `$pageID` isn't empty before running query
- Wrap it with single/double quotes (`WHERE owner = '$pageID' ORDER BY created`) so query will not fail even if `$pageID` is empty (it'll just return empty results)

Comment: Not quite the solution, but, certainly put me on the right track. It helped me to discover that apparently Facebook for whatever reason on occasion returns an empty value for the Page ID. I have now accommodated for this and have a second way implemented. Thank you!